# Installing security camera outdoors

Tags: drill, outdoor, security

My friend is planning on installing some security cameras on the outside of his house and I'll be helping him. I have a few questions:

- How do we avoid drilling through wires and pipes? Is there a rule-of-thumb for were these are normally located in the walls?
- Should we use a long drill-bit to go all the way through to the inside?
- What is an easy way to route cables (data and power) from the outside into the inside of the house?
- Are plain old wood screws good enough to mount the camera securely to the outside? Or should we use something extra for mounting?

We've never done this before, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I assume these will be mounted high on walls so *normally* you would not have any water supply pipes there.  Look on the roof and in the attic for where sanitary sewer vents are. Electrical wiring is another matter. You could have wires going down into the top plate of an exterior wall. Look inside the room and see if there is a receptacle in the wall below where you want to penetrate. Get a stud finder with electrical detection and metal detection.  When drilling go through the cavity then stop and probe in the cavity for any obstruction. You could get a borescope.

Comment: What will the cameras be attached to?  Siding?  If so, what kind?

Comment: Yes, we're thinking of mounting it to the sides of the house. I don't know the exact material that the side is made of, but it looks similar to shingles on the roof of a house.

Answer (score 2):

There are some common spots for an outdoor security camera, soffit, overhang, upper wall. Yes, it's important to watch out for the hidden cables or wires hidden buried in the wall. Here is a useful guide that you could look into when you are installing the camera outside https://www.securitycameraking.com/securityinfo/cctv-installation-and-wiring-options/

For outdoor mounting, secure the camera by using screws are common and useful.